# Draw the stack frame and determin addresses of locals assuming x86 calling convention

Tags: assembly, x86

```
int fun (short a,long b, int c){short q; char s[3]; int y; }
```

My stack frame looks like this: (I'm not sure)

[image]

Two questions:

1. Is it good?
2. In this convention stack is with increasing addresses and heap with decreasing?

Comment: You seem to have allocated 6 bytes for `s` and 4 for `a`. Also what's the striped slot after `a`? `b` uses 4 bytes as is normally the case on x86, but then why is it drawn with a split box as if it took 8?

Comment: I'll add it. So everything else seems to be fine?

Comment: Also didn't mention that long in my case uses 8 bits (I was told the size of long = 8)

Comment: Well, the diagram shows `b` from 16 to 20, that's 4 bytes not 8.

Comment: The extra slot is because of size-alignment rule

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it should be 24 instead of 20

Comment: @Jester Updated the picture, is it now correct?

Comment: 2. the stack grows from high addresses to low.  Some people draw it with low addresses at the top like you've done, so it grows upwards and the "top of stack" is on top.  But other people choose to draw it the other way up, so the stack actually grows downwards, matching the way I think about it.  Both ways are correct; your numeric labels have sensible offsets from the frame pointer, assuming the callee chooses to make a legacy stack frame with EBP at all.

Comment: The layout of the locals is not standardized, but what you have shown is a possible option. It would be more efficient to put `s` at `-8` and `q` at `-4` though.

Comment: You now have an extra stack slot of padding after `a`.  Depending on the calling convention / ABI, `alignof(long)` may only be 4, so `b` can be passed on the stack in the 2 slots after `a`.  i.e. `a` at EBP+8, `b` at EBP+12.

Comment: 2. As far as understand in my picture stack is on top from FP to -12 and heap is from FP to 28 or 8 to 28? sizeof stack = 12 and sizeof heap = 20 or 28?

Comment: Heap is not in your diagram. All of that is stack.

Comment: no, the locations above FP are still part of the stack!  The heap will be far away from the stack, perhaps near the bottom of virtual address space, while the stack is usually allocated near the top.  So lots more heap and more stack can be allocated before the collide.

Comment: Anyway, adding some `='a'` and so on to your code can get a compiler to generate asm that shows you the locations where it put the variables: https://godbolt.org/z/ye4OUy.  I had to use `long long` to get a 64-bit integer type when FP and the return address were still only 4 bytes; no standard x86 calling convention / ABI has 64-bit long in 32-bit mode.  But anyway, both MSVC on Windows and gcc on Linux agree that a,b,c are at 8,12,20

Comment: So both versions are good? (a,b,c are at 8,12,20 and a,b,c are at 8,16,24) or just the first one?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a single x86 calling convention and the layout of the local variables is not defined by the calling convention anyway.
The question is thus not framed correctly, even before taking into consideration how the C types are implemented.

If we assume:

- `stdcall` or `cdecl` calling convention.
- The compiler is using a frame pointer.
- The compiler will align data at least on their natural boundaries.
- `short`, `int`, `long` are 16, 32, 32 bits respectively and aligned on 2, 4 and 4 bytes respectively.

then I'd expect this stack (note that I use the hex notation):

```
[EBP +10h] c
[EBP +0Ch] b
[EBP +08h] a
[EBP +04h] Return address
[EBP +00h] Old EBP
[EBP -02h] q
[EBP -05h] s
[EBP -0ch] y
```

That's what [Clang does without optimisations](https://godbolt.org/z/Kr6P66) except that it preserves 3 registers thereby shifting the offsets down by 12.

`a`, `b` and `c` are pushed on the stack in reverse order, all types must occupy a number of bytes multiple of 4.

Locals allocation is not absolute, it depends on the surrounding code (usage of non volatile registers, calls, temporaries, stack protections and so on) and in this case, where there is no code or context at all, the question is a bit vacuous.
Using only the last two assumptions<sup>1</sup> we can put `q` at `[EBP -02h]` since `q` is 2 bytes and need to be at an address multiple of 2; `s` is at `[EBP -05h]` since it is 3 bytes and is byte-aligned; finally `y` *could go* at `[EBP -09h]` from a size-only perspective but since it must be aligned on 4-bytes, it goes at `[EBP -0ch]`.
Note that all the reasoning above exploit the fact that `EBP` is aligned on 4-bytes.

---

<sup>1</sup> We also assume that locals are laid out in reverse order: the last one in order of declaration is laid out at a lower address.

Comment: According to a comment, the OP is using a non-standard ABI with 64-bit `long` in 32-bit mode.  As [I commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291230/draw-the-stack-frame-and-determin-addresses-of-locals-assuming-x86-calling-conve/53304162#comment93464468_53291230), you get args at +8, +12, and +20 if you use `long long` because 64-bit integers are still only aligned by 4 bytes, not naturally aligned.

Comment: @PeterCordes IIRC, arguments are not usually aligned on 32-bit x86, only padded to be a multiple of four bytes. Though, I may remember wrong.  Yes, using a 64-bit `long` will shift the other argument by 4. I hope the OP will do the math themselves.

Comment: That's because `alignof(long long)` is only 4.  Same as for struct packing.  Giving `long long` natural alignment is only an optimization that's done whenever possible (outside of structs and arg-passing).  If you passed an 8-byte or 16-byte aligned type, there would have to be padding.  (And IIRC, i386 System V mentions this for `__m128` args that don't fit in registers).  I don't know what Windows calling conventions do about passing types that guarantee more than 4 byte alignment.

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right: the i386 ABI mandates alignments for the arguments (and for the end of parameter block as a whole). I didn't know that. `long long` is aligned on 4 bytes. Microsoft, instead, is too vague in its page on x86-32 calling conventions. Their compiler doesn't seem to align `long long` on 8B when passed as a parameter and larger types are passed as pointers.